# I'm trying to remove empty items in listbox in C#

Tags: c#, listbox

So i want to remove empty items in listbox like whitespace so Far I have this code. But the compiler is giving me an error

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox2.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (listBox2.Items[i].ToString = " "){//ERROR*
        listBox2.Items.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

*Cannot convert method group 'ToString' to non-delegate type 'bool'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ToString` is a method, so you need it to be `ToString()`, and equality comparisons are performed with two equals signs `==`, not one. One equals sign is for assignment.

With that said, to iterate over your collection and remove items by their index, you'll want to go in reverse. You'll notice that as you remove items, your item count will obviously drop, so your loop will not behave like you think it will. So go for something like this:

```
int count = listBox2.Items.Count;
for (int i = count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    if (listBox2.Items[i].ToString() == " ")
    {
        listBox2.Items.RemoveAt(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, I should point out that this will only match strings that are exactly one space and one space only.  To match all whitespace strings, use `String.IsNullOrWhitespace(listbox2.Items[i].ToString())`

Comment: @Miff, That's a good point for to consider. It is a .NET 4 method, so it may not be available if working in a 3.5 or less framework.

Comment: In case of < .NET4, you could still use `string.IsNullOrEmpty(foo.Trim())`. And I'm pretty sure that's what the author of question intended, not the single space.

Comment: Thanks, your soloution did the trick. And I ended up using string.IsNullOrEmpty()

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(listBox2.Items[i].ToString())){
```

However!  Since you're removing items, that means that the enumerator won't work properly.  If your list box items are

- "a"
- " "
- "b"

Then your code will:

- Keep a. (Index 0)
- Remove " ". (Index 1, "b" becomes the new index 1)
- Throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. (Because there is not item 2)

Instead, try

```
List<int> itemsToRemove = new List<int>(); // using System.Collections.Generic
for (int i = 0; i <= listBox2.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(listBox2.Items[i].ToString())){
        itemsToRemove.Append(i);
    }
}
foreach (int i in itemsToRemove){
    listBox2.Items.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Comment: Or, change the original `for` cycle to decrease: `for (int i = listBox2.Items.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)`. It'll be ok then, no need to create a list and run two cycles.

Comment: String.IsNullOrWhitespace is only available by default in .NET 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
> for (int i = 0; i <= listBox2.Items.Count; i++)
>               {
>                   if (listBox2.Items[i].ToString() == "") //Remove ' ' space
>                       listBox2.Items.RemoveAt(i);
>                   }
>               }
```

Comment: Code will still error as missing equals sign and wont match white spaces as required by question.  What you have put will only find empty strings (once error is fixed).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're a VB-guy.
In C-based languages (like C#) there's (unlike in VB) two different operators for assigning stuff and checking stuff (I don't know the real terms). For checking if two things are equal, you use a double = (==). So what you're doing in your if statement, is assigning " " to the listbox item. This obviously doesn't return a boolean (which is what if needs). In pre-c# languages, this could cause really hard-to-find bugs, because there was no warning.

In VB, you can call a method without using parentheses. In c#, they are always needed. The compiler will think you want to store the address of the method in a delegate if you leave them out (like using AddressOf in VB.Net). When you make those two changes (and, indeed, loop backwards like Anthony Pegram said), all will work fine.